# update user session when user change locale in Symfony

Tags: symfony, security, translation

In my Symfony 4.4 application i create the `UserLocaleSubscriber` which works fine but when user change your locale must logout ang login for change transaltion language. I try to use `EqutableInterface` to update the user session without logout user.

```
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if ($user instanceof self)
        {
            if ($user->getLocale() != $this->locale) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

but stiil when i change the user locale i must logoout and login for using new locale. Is there any option to change language without logout?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to logout at all, just redirect to /en or /es depend on your language and routing.